# Echoing the windows path in python

Tags: python, windows

Essentially what I am trying to do is

```
from subprocess import call
print call(['echo', '%path%'])
```

however 'echo' is not recognized as an executable is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a windows computer, but you could probably use `os.environ` to get it without relying on an external utility -- On *NIX it looks something like:

```
import os
print (os.environ['PATH'])
```

Answer (score 2):

mgilson has the better advice, but anyway, FYI, `echo` is a builtin command of `cmd.exe`:

```
subprocess.call("CMD /C ECHO %PATH%")
```

Answer (score -1):

`echo` is not an executable, it is a shell command.

To execute shell commands, use:

```
subprocess.call("echo %PATH%", shell=True)
```

Comment: If you use `shell=True`, you'll probably want to condense the list down into a single string.

Comment: Using `shell=True` is not needed in this case.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Really? Can you execute a shell command without using shell=True?

Comment: Sure, as *shell* is plain executable you run it the same way you run any other executable.

Comment: Yes of course, but using shell=True is still the most straightforward way to do what the original questions asks: Execute shell commands using the subprocess module.